# How to design a database schema for an item with multiple photos

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to design a database schema to keep an item persistence.
For each item, I have

1. title
2. 1 or multiple photos.

I think my database schema needs

1. id for primary key
2. string for title

My question is how to preserve multiple photos for each item? each item can have 1 or multiple photos associated with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a second table, where you store the photos, along with the id of the item they belong to.  Multiple rows in this second table (one per photo) could reference the same item.  The item id that you store in your photos table is a foreign key into the items table.  For example, let's say your items table contains the following three items:

```
 id | title
----+-------
  1 | House
  2 | Car
  3 | Tree
```

Let's say that House and Tree each only have one photo, but Car has 2 photos.  You might store the following in your photos table:

```
 id | item_id | photo
----+---------+-----------
  1 |       1 | pic.jpg
  2 |       2 | front.jpg
  3 |       2 | side.jpg
  4 |       3 | green.jpg
```

In the table above, you can see that `pic.jpg` belongs to the first item (House), `front.jpg` and `side.jpg` belong to the second item (Car) and `green.jpg` belongs to the third item (Tree).

If you wanted to find the title and photos for your second item, you could run the following query:

```
SELECT items.title, photos.photo
FROM items JOIN photos ON items.id = photos.item_id
WHERE items.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a relational database? If yes...

If the photos can only have one parent, then you just need a table for the photos that has foreign key to the parent table.

If the photos can have have multiple parents, you'll need to use a many-to-many table to link the records from your item table to the records in the photo table. The many-to-many table will have foreign keys for both the item and photo primary keys.